# when use below code to store image in sqlite, I get only first image , the application not restore to me the other images by the id

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, bitmap

when I use this code to store image and restore it from SQLite . it insert only one image (the first one ) and when i restore the image by id it also restore the first image only .

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:hint="enter name"
    android:id="@+id/nametxt"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
    />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:hint="enter id"
        android:id="@+id/idtxt"
        android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save Image Sqlite"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:textSize="20dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Image From Sqlite"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:maxHeight="120dp"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mahmoudbelal.navigator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;
static  EditText name,id;   

  static   ImageView Img,Img2;
    Button Save,Get;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
id= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idtxt);
        Img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Get = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nametxt);

        Img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                // Start the Intent
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
            }
        });

        Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               try {    

                   Img.buildDrawingCache();
                   Bitmap bitmap=Img.getDrawingCache();

                   ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                   byte[] img = bos.toByteArray();

                  DBAdapter D=new DBAdapter();
                   D.open(MainActivity.this);
                   String myname=name.getText().toString();
                   String myid=id.getText().toString();

                   D.insert_user_data(myid,myname,img);

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inserted Data well !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   name.setText(" ");
                   id.setText(" ");

               }catch (Exception e){
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
               }
            }
        });    
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//\

        Get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DBAdapter D=new DBAdapter();
                D.open(MainActivity.this);
               String use_id=id.getText().toString();
                D.Get_user_data(use_id);
                if (DBAdapter.ok.equals("1")){
                  //  Img2.setImageBitmap(DBAdapter.bmp);
                   // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "name is  =  "+DBAdapter.s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    name.setText(""+DBAdapter.s);

                }else
                {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error y m3lm ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }            }
        });
    }    

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);   

        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == this.RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);    
//-0-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor actualimagecursor = managedQuery(photoUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            actualimagecursor.moveToFirst();    
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            cursor.close();    
            Img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }}    
    }
```

DBAdapter.java

```
package com.example.mahmoudbelal.navigator;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class DBAdapter {
    // first step:create table
  static   Bitmap bmp;
   static String s="";
    private int version=1;
    private String DatabaseName="DNAA";
    private String TableName="user";
    static  String ok;
//                             --------------------------------------------------                             //    
    private String create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(id varchar,name varchar,img blob);";   

    // second step:helper class
    class DbHellper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{    

        public DbHellper(Context context){
            super(context , DatabaseName , null , version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(create_table);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {    
            db.execSQL("Drop table If Exists "+TableName);
            onCreate(db);    
        }
    }    

    private DbHellper DB_helper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter open(Context conn){
        DB_helper = new DbHellper(conn);
        db = DB_helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

        // activity
    }

    private void close (){
        db.close();
    }
    int i = 0;

    public void insert_user_data (String id, String name, byte[] ii){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();    

        cv.put("id" , id);
        cv.put("name" , name);
        cv.put("img" , ii);

        db.insert(TableName, null, cv);    
    }

    public void updateSection(String username , String password , int rowId){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("username" , username);
        cv.put("password" , password);
        db.update(TableName, cv, "_id =" + rowId, null);
    }

    // Login method
    public  void  Get_user_data (String id){

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name,img FROM user where id='"+id+"'", null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
             s= c.getString(0);
            byte[] i=c.getBlob(1);

             bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(i,0,i.length);
            MainActivity.Img2.setImageBitmap(bmp);

          ok="1";
        } else {
            ok="0";
        }
    }
    // delete data
    public void deleteSection(int rowId){
        db.delete(TableName, "_id =" + rowId, null);
    }

    public Cursor getAllSections (){
        return db.query(TableName,new String []{"username","password"},null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public Cursor getSection (String whereClause){
        return db.query(TableName,new String []{"_id","name","devices"},whereClause,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the record: you dropped quite some code on us. Which is in general not such a good idea ... ( see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) ... but if you do so: please make sure that **all** of that code is formatted/indented correctly. And hint: when you start marking different sections within your source code using comments; consider simply using multiple methods instead. And finally: dont be surprised if there isnt too much help on so much input. You see, were are not a free debugging service. So the reasonable answer here: learn how to use a debugger!

Comment: You **never move your cursor**! That's why you are always pointed to the first record, after calling `moveToFirst()`

Comment: As @GhostCat said debug your code. Anyway as I see your code u r not saving any second image in DB?

Comment: what is your suggestions ?

Comment: My suggestions: **1** - Learn how databases work in general. **2** - Apply that knowledge to Android. **3** - This is not a Google replacement.

Answer (score -1):

this may help you

String[] columns =
{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };

```
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;

    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,null,null, orderBy + " DESC");

    this.imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        imageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));

        System.out.println("==here you will get all the images path ;=> "+imageUrls.get(i));
    }
```

for your reference check this :
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/